# Selenium ожидания доступности кнопки

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Делаю кликер, который нажимает на кнопку, как только эта кнопка становится доступна (у класса кнопки сервером убирается disabled). Но почему то даже тогда, когда кнопка становится доступна, программа не нажимает ее. Использую нахождение по xpath потому что кнопка на сайте часто меняет свой класс.
Вот код функции:

```
url = input()
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)
       try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 900)
            ButtBuy = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@text, "Купить")]')))
        except:
            print("Ошибка нахождения кнопки покупки, приложение закроется через 30 сек.")
            time.sleep(30)
            browser.quit()
        else:
            ButtBuy.click()
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
            ButtConfirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]')))
            ButtConfirm.click()
```

Поясн. Buttbuy это сама кнопка покупки, а buttconfirm это кнопка подтверждения, которая появляется потом.

Примерный сценарий использования: Ввел url, отошел от компьютера, а через 10 минут кнопка становится активна и программа автоматически ее нажимает.(10 минут это не точное значение, может быть как 3, 5, 6 и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вариант через бесконечный цикл, который будет раз в 30 секунд проверять элемент на видимость, и если он увидит кнопку - нажмет на нее, если нет - вернется к началу цикла

```py
try:
    while True:

        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 900)
        time.sleep(30)
        if ButtBuy = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
    '//button[contains(@text, "Купить")]'))):

            ButtBuy.click()
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
            ButtConfirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]')))
            ButtConfirm.click()
    else: 
        continue  
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    pass
```

Comment: Что нужно дописать для того, чтобы при успешном нажатии цикл прерывался?

Comment: Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Дополнил ответ, но для общего развития можете почитать про `pyHook`

Comment: Большое спасибо, но я имел в виду успешное нажатие программы на кнопку

Comment: Я буду очень признателен, если вы скинете код, который выходит из цикла и идет дальше по программе при успешном нажатии на кнопку.